# How to set tooltips to display percentages to match axis in Google Visualization Line Chart?

Tags: google-visualization, number-formatting, linechart

The tooltips can be set to display percentages using the following code:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      fractionDigits: 2,
      suffix: '%'
    });
formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to first column.
```

Is there a way for NumberFormat to multiply each element by 100? Otherwise the tooltip appears as .50%.

I am using `vAxis.format = "format:'#%' "` which does multiply by 100. So .5 is displayed as 50% on the vertical axis.

According to the documentation([icu-project.org/apiref](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details)), this can be overwritten by enclosing the % in single quotes, but this did not work.

The net result is that the tooltips do not match the axis. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ 
  pattern: '#%', 
  fractionDigits: 2
});
```

Thanks to http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/

Comment: Corrrect,  just then add your line  :    formatter.format(data, 1);

Answer (score 22):

I got this working by specifying a formatter exactly as you do:

```
var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(tableData);
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 2,
    suffix: '%'
});
formatter.format(chartData, 1);
```

The `1` in the last call means the second column, in which I have float values.

Then I specify a format for the axis in the chart options, escaping the percentage sign as pointed out by documentation and others here:

```
var chartOptions = {
    vAxis: { format: '#\'%\'' }
};
```

I then draw the chart:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(chartData, chartOptions);
```

This renders a left side axis with values like `10%`, `20%` and so on. And the tooltips looks like the default one but with a percentage like `10.10%`, `20.20%` and so on.

If you want two fraction digits in the left side axis as well, use this as format in the chart options instead:

```
vAxis: { format: '#.00\'%\'' }
```

Comment: Thanks for that trick of wrapping the % in single quotes - otherwise the axis values are multiplied by 100! Drove me mad ...

Comment: I think it's important to note that you have to format the chart before you actually draw the chart. I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working for me... it's because I tried to use `formatter.format(chartData, 1)` AFTER I had already created chart. In my case I had multiple columns that needed formatting so I put that code in my script 4 times, each with a different column number.

Answer (score 3):

You must surround the percent (%) symbol itself in single quotes.

The line I used to do this looks like this: `options['vAxis'] = {'format': "#,###'%'"};`

Combining this with your formatter above, you can make the vertical axis have a percent symbol and also make the tooltip include it too.

Comment: I don't think this will affect the tooltips. I think it sets the labels of the axis.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... So this is a little late. I admit I didn't need this seven years ago. Nevertheless, this worked for me.

```
var rows = data.getNumberOfRows();

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    data.setFormattedValue(i, 4, (data.getFormattedValue(i, 4)*100).toFixed(1) + "%"); //LY
    data.setFormattedValue(i, 3, (data.getFormattedValue(i, 3)*100).toFixed(1) + "%"); //TY
}
```

In my case, I am using four columns, two of which are assigned to the right axis with percentages. I wanted those columns' tooltips to reflect the proper percentage rather than the decimal representation.

Here is a link to the Google docs:

> https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setFormattedValue

I hope this helps some random stranger looking for it. ;)