# googleVis chart Tooltip: Show percent (via formatter?)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, shiny, googlevis

I have created a chart using googleVis in a shiny app but I cannot find a way to set the number in the tooltip as percentage.

I have seen that this is possible if you specify a [formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724451/how-to-set-tooltips-to-display-percentages-to-match-axis-in-google-visualization). How could I possibly implement such a solution for a shiny app?

I know I could customize tooltips via html using roles but I don't want to go down that path.

Comment: I just answered a similar question here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724451/how-to-set-tooltips-to-display-percentages-to-match-axis-in-google-visualization/48874196#48874196 Cheers

Comment: I just answered a similar question here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724451/how-to-set-tooltips-to-display-percentages-to-match-axis-in-google-visualization/48874196#48874196 Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use roles without using html code written by yourself:

```
    library(googleVis)
    dat <- data.frame(Year=2010:2013,
                      Sales=c(600, 1500, 800, 1000),
                      Sales.html.tooltip=c('15.4%',
                                           '38.4%',
                                           '20.5%',
                                           '25.7%'),
                      Sales.certainty=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
    plot(
      gvisColumnChart(dat, xvar='Year', 
                      yvar=c('Sales', 'Sales.certainty', 'Sales.html.tooltip')
      )
    )
```

More examples: [Using Roles via googleVis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html)